# Why can't I retrieve token key of salt machine in postman

Tags: curl, postman, salt-stack

The salt server is working completely fine, I can get the token key and I am able to execute the commands.  for developing an  application  I tried to  test by passing  a token key request through curl command in postman. However, I could not able to get the token key. Even though, I  could able to execute remaining commands in postman. It is showing server error 500. could you Please let me know whats going wrong?

post: https://10.xxx.xxx.33:8000

Authorization tab : No Auth

header:

Accept:  Application/json
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body:

x-www-form-urlencoded

username: rach
password: paul1234
eauth: pam

This is the output.
 "status": 500,
  "return": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/netapi/rest_cherrypy/app.py\", line 534, in hypermedia_handler\n    ret = cherrypy.serving.request._hypermedia_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py\", line 61, in **call**\n    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/netapi/rest_cherrypy/app.py\", line 960, in POST\n    token=cherrypy.session.get('token')))\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/netapi/rest_cherrypy/app.py\", line 802, in exec_lowstate\n    ret = self.api.run(chunk)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/netapi/**init**.py\", line 62, in run\n    raise salt.exceptions.SaltException('No client specified')\nSaltException: No client specified\n"
}

Comment: Please show some code and the results you're getting. 500 normally means the server had some issue. I get that whenever I have PHP that is invalid for instance on one of my servers.

Comment: sorry,I reformatted the qn. please take back the negative vote if that is the reason.

Comment: @keith I couldn't find many examples for token request. So, I am not sure if I can use the token request for it. The token request in curl is ....paul@DC2Salt:~$ curl -si -k https://localhost:8000/login -H "Accept: application/json" -d username='sdfds' -d password='dfdsf' -d eauth='pam' | grep token | awk -F"\"" '{print $12}'^C

Comment: The key to your issue is 'salt.exceptions.SaltException('No client specified')\nSaltException: No client specified\n" }'

Comment: I use newman to run postman tests from the command line.

Comment: I created a postman-runner here https://bitbucket.org/csmu/postman-runner

Comment: thats a good point Keith. but  the thing I was wondering I am able to talk to the server with those credentials. Do you think is it because I put in the wrong place. or Do I have to put anything other than the user profile created in the minion.

Comment: The first thing to do is to sort out that exception. That's why you're getting a 500 status. Then you can reevaluate from there.